# SELECT from two tables where no related rows in second table

Tags: mysql, sql

I am executing this SQL Query:

```
SELECT * FROM tickets t 
WHERE t.status <> 'Completed' 
AND NOT EXISTS (SELECT u.ticketnumber 
                FROM ticket_updates u 
                WHERE u.type = 'update' AND u.ticketnumber = t.ticketnumber)
```

that selects from 2 tables where there are no rows in the ticket_updates table where `ticketnumber = ticketnumber` in both tables.

How can i change this Query to return rows where there is no rows in ticket_updates `where customer <> 'Y'`

Comment: please set up SQLFiddle or provide sample data and desired outcome.

Answer (score 0):

Just add another `AND` condition in your sub query

```
SELECT * FROM tickets t 
WHERE t.status <> 'Completed' 
AND NOT EXISTS (SELECT u.ticketnumber 
                FROM ticket_updates u 
                WHERE u.type = 'update' AND u.ticketnumber = t.ticketnumber
                AND u.customer <> 'Y'
               )
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT t.*, tu.* 
FROM tickets t
LEFT JOIN ticket_updates tu ON t.ticketnumber = tu.ticketnumber 
WHERE tu.ticketnumber IS NULL AND t.status <> 'Completed' AND tu.customer <> 'Y'
```